# OrCreateDatabase error nativescript sqlite

Tags: sqlite, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

When I create localDB using nativescript-sqlite plugin it is throwing following error.

`SQLITE.CONSTRUCTOR -  Open DB Error Error: java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method open OrCreateDatabase on class android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase`

Why it is showing this error

Comment: post any code related to the error above and follow the best practice when posting a question in SO - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a few months later but maybe it will help to someone else. I was struggling with same issue for about few hours. In my case root cause was a minor update of *nativescript-sqlite* dependency from 1.1.7 to a newer one (minor) 1.1.11. 
Dependency declaration looked like below: 
 `"dependencies": {
    "nativescript-sqlite": "~1.1.7",
  },`

and putting exact version as dependency solved the issue:

 `"dependencies": {
    "nativescript-sqlite": "1.1.7",
  },`

Of course please reinstall dependencies after patching code. Hope it will save someone time. It's a work-around and probably at the end you'll have to refactor code and update to version 2.x.